# Scrapy: Crawled but not scraped any data

Tags: python, scrapy

I wrote the following code to scrape Booking.com given the name of the city. Ideally, the program should find out all the hotels that are available in the city and scrape all the reviews for each hotel. Unfortunately, it will scrape only a few hotels and only the first 75 reviews of those hotels. Will you please tell me what am I doing wrong here??

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from booking_spider.items import BookingSpiderItem


class PerhotelrevSpider(Spider):
    name = 'perhotelrev'
    allowed_domains = ['booking.com']
    #start_urls = ['https://booking.com/reviews/us/hotel/maison-st-charles-quality-inn-suites.html?/']
    start_urls = ['https://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?ss=New%20Orleans&']
    #handle_httpstatus_list = [301, 302]
    def parse(self, response):
        all_hotels = response.xpath('.//*[@class="sr-hotel__title  \n"]')
        for ahotel in all_hotels:
            hotel_name = ahotel.xpath('.//*[@class="sr-hotel__name\n"]/text()').extract_first().replace('\n','')
            hotel_url = ahotel.xpath('.//*[@class="hotel_name_link url"]/@href').extract_first().replace('\n','')
            full_hotel_url = 'https://www.booking.com'+str(hotel_url)
            request = scrapy.Request(full_hotel_url, callback = self.parse_hotels)
            request.meta['adict'] = {'HotelName':hotel_name}
            yield request

        next_page = response.xpath('.//*[@class="bui-pagination__item bui-pagination__next-arrow"]/a/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page_url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_hotels(self, response):
        adict = response.meta['adict']
        hotel_name = adict['HotelName']
        #hotel_name = response.xpath('.//*[@class="hp__hotel-name"]/text()')[1].extract().replace('\n','')
        image_urls = response.xpath('.//*[@class="b_nha_hotel_small_images hp_thumbgallery_with_counter"]/a/@href').extract()
        all_facilities = response.xpath('.//*[@class="facilitiesChecklistSection"]/ul/li/span/text()').extract()
        all_facilities = [x.replace('\n','') for x in all_facilities]
        important_facility = response.xpath('.//*[@class="important_facility "]/@data-name-en').extract()
        #print(hotel_name)
        all_review_url = response.xpath('.//*[@class="show_all_reviews_btn"]/@href').extract_first()

        adict = {   'HotelName':hotel_name,
                    'ImageUrls':image_urls,
                    'Facilities':all_facilities,
                    'MainFacilities':important_facility
                }

        if all_review_url is not None:
            review_url = "https://booking.com"+all_review_url
            request = scrapy.Request(review_url, callback=self.parse_review)
            request.meta['adict'] = adict
            yield request


    def parse_review(self, response):
        allreviewsinpage = response.xpath('.//*[@itemprop="review"]')
        adict = response.meta['adict']
        hotel_name = adict['HotelName']
        image_urls = adict['ImageUrls']
        all_facilities = adict['Facilities']
        important_facility = adict['MainFacilities']

        for eachreview in allreviewsinpage:
            username = eachreview.xpath('.//p[@class="reviewer_name"]/*[@itemprop="name"]/text()').extract_first()
            usercountry = eachreview.xpath('.//*[@itemprop="nationality"]/*[@itemprop="name"]/text()').extract_first()
            numreviewgiven = eachreview.xpath('.//*[@class="review_item_user_review_count"]/text()').extract_first()
            useragegroup = eachreview.xpath('.//*[@class="user_age_group"]/text()').extract_first()
            heading = eachreview.xpath('.//*[@class="review_item_header_content\n"]/*[@itemprop="name"]/text()').extract_first()
            neg_rev = eachreview.xpath('.//p[@class="review_neg "]/*[@itemprop="reviewBody"]/text()').extract_first()
            pos_rev = eachreview.xpath('.//p[@class="review_pos "]/*[@itemprop="reviewBody"]/text()').extract_first()
            tagging = eachreview.xpath('.//ul[@class="review_item_info_tags"]/*[@class="review_info_tag "]/text()').extract()
            stayedin = eachreview.xpath('.//p[@class="review_staydate "]/text()').extract_first()
            givenscore = eachreview.xpath('.//span[@class="review-score-badge"]/text()').extract_first()


            l = ItemLoader(item=BookingSpiderItem(), selector=response)
            l.add_value('HotelName',hotel_name)
            #l.add_value('ImageUrls',image_urls)
            l.add_value('Facilities',all_facilities)
            l.add_value('MainFacilities',important_facility)
            l.add_value('UserName',username)
            l.add_value('UserCountry',usercountry)
            l.add_value('NumReviewGiven',numreviewgiven)
            l.add_value('UserAgeGroup',useragegroup)
            l.add_value('Heading',heading)
            l.add_value('NegativeReview',neg_rev)
            l.add_value('PositiveReview',pos_rev)
            l.add_value('SelfTag',tagging)
            l.add_value('StayDate',stayedin)
            l.add_value('GivenScore',givenscore)
            yield l.load_item()
        next_page = response.xpath('.//*[@class="page_link review_next_page"]/a/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page_url, callback=self.parse_review)
```

Comment: Where does booking_spider come from?

Comment: @keineahnung2345 booking_spider is where I have a class to save the scraped data as field item. Please check out the following google drive, where the complete code is available: [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14HkHw3EBamshYvtg3TOuTu2hnRHgSFpz?usp=sharing)
Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Limit first 75 reviews could be set by Booking api. Then nothing wrong with yours code. To deal with it you could find information about limits in documentation of booking api or use libs like request or selenium do scrape data without api.

Comment: Can you find more than 75 reviews if you access yourself from the website?

Comment: @Paweł : Before trying to automate the scraping city-wide, my code had the last function (**parse_review**) only. With a given hotel link it would then scrape all reviews for that hotel. So I am sure it is not an API restriction. I am not scraping using API.

Comment: @Gallaecio Yes, each hotel has more than ~2000 rewviews.

Comment: It is specially weird that it stops at 75 when pages have 10 items each. Have you tried printing the last page you get to a file, to see what it has? Have you tried limiting your crawl again to a single hotel, and see if for that hotel your current code works as your old code?

Comment: I ended up splitting the spider into 3 separate ones and that did the job right. Thanks everyone